# The background image in HTML could not cover the full width even I had already set the width in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the background image covering the full width of the page by putting `min-width:100%` in CSS but the section is not covering the full width as the picture shown. Even I tried to set `background-size: cover` it does not work as expected.[The image does not cover the full width of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIG2y.jpg)

```css
.slide {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2 rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 60 rem;
  min-width: 100 %;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide" style="background:url(images/slide_1.png) no-repeat">
  <div class="content">
    <span>Explore, Discover, Travel</span>
    <h3>Travel around the world</h3>
    <a class="btn" href="">Discover more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect the image to be covered with full width by putting width property in CSS but it was not shown as expected.

Comment: This lacks context. We don't know how `.home` is formatted to begin with, or if any ancestors further up the tree might limit the width. Please always provide a proper [mre] of your issue, when asking questions like this.

Comment: `background-size: 100%` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the inline styles of the `div` with class `.slide`:

```css
.slide {
  background: url(images/slide_1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 60rem;
  /* min-width: 100%; Remove this line */
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <div class="content">
    <span>Explore, Discover, Travel</span>
    <h3>Travel around the world</h3>
    <a class="btn" href="">Discover more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you add `width: 100%;` or `min-width: 100%;` it causes an unwanted overflow-x.